# Is it OK to change my question title?

Tags: support, edits

[How can I verify that my SQL Server edition is Express?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125506/although-in-ms-sql-not-express-i-have-a-limit-of-10gb-per-database/125508#125508)

This question of mine went in an another direction. I don't want to delete it, because I believe it can serve someone someday. But I think that the question should be titled differently. Is it OK to change the question title to serve the acquired answers and comment better?

What is the best action I can take here?

Comment: What do you think the title should be?

Comment: "How can I verify that my MS SQL version is Express?" would be my first try

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes.** In fact, we would encourage you to edit your title to more accurately reflect the real question and the answer you received. Just be sure that the title, question, and answer make sense together.

By the way, the question [cannot be deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) (by you) because it has an accepted answer (see the link for a full description of when you can, and cannot, delete a question).

I also improved your question title here :)

Comment: Or because it has an upvoted answer (the OP can't unaccept+delete).

Answer (score 6):

You can edit your own question as you like if you think it's an improvement.

If the edit deviates from the original question so much it basically becomes a completely different question (and maybe even invalidate answers) you should probably be going for a new question.